# Mongodb: Possible to enlarge a capped collection?

Tags: mongodb

If a collection is created as capped, is it possible to increase the cap without losing data?

Or to increase the cap without recreating the whole collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't alter a capped collection size to make it larger (or smaller for that matter) without dropping it and recreating it - it is created with a fixed size.  However you could use [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) to dump out the existing data, then drop the collection, recreate it with the larger size and then restore the dumped data.

Assuming you are making it bigger, all the data will fit in the new collection. Unfortunately, this will mean that you will need to stop writing to that collection for the duration of this work, there is no way to do it without taking some down time for the collection in question.

There is an existing feature request to add resizing capabilities to MongoDB, but as of writing this it is not yet scheduled. See here for voting and watching purposes:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1864

Answer (score 2):

```
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "events", size: 10 * 1024 * 1024});
```

Will set the byte size of the capped collection (larger or smaller). It will keep the documents (that fit). It will drop the indexes, you'll have to recreate those. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22814104/46572) answer and the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/).

This is pretty fast also, ~200ms on my MBP to double the 10MB collection in the example.

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#change-a-capped-collection-s-size

New in version 6.0:

```
db.runCommand( { collMod: "log", cappedSize: 100000 } )
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/189474)